# Elements tweaks does not show up/open and my computer crashes when I reboot

Tags: thirdpartyapps

I tried installing elementary tweaks tool with the following commands and it didn't work. Then when I rebooted the system it crashed after login, this happens every time I try. The commands I used are below

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Answer (score 1):

My computer no longer crashes but the elementary tweaks tool still does not show up anywhere. :( also when trying some of your commands the terminal said it couldn't locate elementary tweaks or something. (sorry I'm not very accurate, novice user here)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove elementary-tweaks --purge
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks -y
```